# Ivy maven compatibility issue

Tags: maven, pom.xml, ivy

I'm trying to add a dependency to an Ivy project. The dependency is like this in maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I've add this to the ivy.xml file:

but when running the resolve task, it give me an error like this:
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.glassfish.hk2#hk2;${hk2.version}: not found

    :: org.glassfish.hk2#spring-bridge;${hk2.version}: not found

    :: javax.ws.rs#javax.ws.rs-api;working@comp: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

[Here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/ext/jersey-spring3/2.7/jersey-spring3-2.7.pom) is the jersey-spring3 pom file. I think the problem is because of the parent tag in the pom file.It is because the hk2.version is defined in the jar's parent pom.

Doesn't Ivy support this feature in pom files?
Any way to solve this problem without adding the transitive dependencies to the main ivy.xml?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce your problem. 40 files downloaded without any issue. I have included my ivy example for reference below.

```
[ivy:resolve] :: resolution report :: resolve 54551ms :: artifacts dl 25244ms
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      compile     |   40  |   40  |   40  |   0   ||   40  |   40  |
    |      runtime     |   40  |   40  |   40  |   0   ||   39  |   39  |
    |       test       |   40  |   40  |   40  |   0   ||   39  |   39  |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Example

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
        <conf name="runtime" description="Additional run-time dependencies" extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test"    description="Required for test only" extends="runtime"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- compile dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.glassfish.jersey.ext" name="jersey-spring3" rev="2.7" conf="compile->default"/>

        <!-- runtime dependencies -->

        <!-- test dependencies -->
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <!--
    ================
    Build properties
    ================
    -->
    <property name="build.dir" location="build"/>

    <available classname="org.apache.ivy.Main" property="ivy.installed"/> 

    <!--
    ===========
    Build targets
    ===========
    -->
    <target name="install-ivy" description="Install ivy" unless="ivy.installed">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar"/>
        <fail message="Ivy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
    </target>

    <target name="resolve" depends="install-ivy" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
        <ivy:resolve/>

        <ivy:report todir='${build.dir}/ivy' graph='false' xml='false'/>

        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path"    conf="test"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleanup build files">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```